# Is there a clean way to associate a python class/function with a row of config info from a DB in flask?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask

I feel like I am approaching this wrong but I'm not sure the best way.

I have a need to process data differently based on who will receive it (from a list of about 100 recipients). Each recipient has a lot of unique processing that needs to be done, for example, I need to be able to output the data readably for each destination, generate links that are unique by destination, etc.

My first thought would be to encapsulate the processing functions in a class for each type of recipient using inheritance. I think this is clean and pythonic.

However, sometimes the processing needs to act differently and this needs to be controlled outside of the codebase. For example, I might need to turn off link generation for one recipient. My thought was to have a table in my site's DB with each recipient as a row and their current flags as columns.

The problem is- how do I correspond the processing classes to the rows of info? I don't like the idea of dumping the classname into a SQL column.

Sorry if this is unclear, as English is not my native language.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you are right, when you are saying "*I am approaching this wrong*".

I also think you are right about the flags: they should be stored with the users somehow (either through foreign key, if many users share similar configurations, or even one-to-one relation, if they have completely different values for flags).

However, you do not need to have separate classes for separate sets of flags. You can define that using single class like that:

```
class UserReport(object):
    def __init__(self, flags):
        self._flags = flags

    def prepare(self):
        if self._flags.get('generate_links'):
            self.generate_links()
        self.build_content()

    def send(self):
        if self._flags.get('send_report'):
            # ... send report here ...
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

That is a very rough example, but should show you, how you can handle several different cases with one class - just allow it to receive some parameters (flags) during instantiation (or later).

Comment: This is what I planned- separate classes for each recipient, not for each set of flags. I was going to put those in a SQL DB. The problem is how do I correspond an instance of the class (say "UserAReport") to its associated flags (the row in the DB)?